How to convert optional fields into type | undefined?
I need to use type without optional fields and convert this type to required fields with type "value | undefined" for optional keys only. How can I do it?
for example:
we have a type:
interface AnyObject {
  a: string;
  b?: number;
}

my new type must convert this to type to:
interface CorrectAnyObject {
  a: string;
  b: number | undefined;
}


Does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Try this:
type CorrectAnyObject = {
  [K in keyof AnyObject]: AnyObject[K] | undefined;
};

[K in keyof AnyObject] is a mapped type that iterates over the keys of AnyObject. For each key K, it creates a new property in CorrectAnyObject with the same key and a type that is either the original type (AnyObject[K]) or undefined.
Based on @LeoDog896 comment which is correct, i'm providing edited type:
type CorrectAnyObject = {
  [K in keyof AnyObject]: AnyObject[K] extends undefined ? AnyObject[K] | undefined : AnyObject[K];
};


This ends up making a: string | undefined: playground
